# Music Player is muted when game is resumed from Fast APP interrupt (Mango)

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

How to not to mute music player? The xna game (mango 7.1) mutes the music from music player how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The music player isn't being muted, it is being stopped. This is by design. When the application begins to run again you would need to restart your music. Keep in mind that when your application got pushed to the background the user could have decided to start playing a song through the media player. So when your application gets brought back to the front it may not have control of the media player.